# Vue testing - How to simulate a long press mouse click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, karma-jasmine, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils

I created a helper to simulate long click with the mouse (press left click for one second for example).

Now I would like to test it with vue-test-utils but I could not find anything about this question.

The only thing I found is the `trigger('mousedown')` function [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/dom-events.html) but it does not solve my issue.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The events `mousedown` and `mouseup` are the 2 'halves' of the `click` event. If you want to simulate a long click for say 1 second, you need to do something like:

```
trigger('mousedown')
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
trigger('mouseup')
```